# Upgrading RAM on ASUS X455LB Laptop

Tags: memory, asus-laptop

So I have this laptop: [ASUSX455LB](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X455LB/specifications/)

Under the section for Memory it says:

> DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 1 x DIMM socket for expansion up to 8 GB SDRAM

I'm just not quite sure what this means. The laptop already came with 4GBs of RAM. And I'm guessing it's an onboard module. Does this mean I can put 4GB more to make it 8GB, or can I put 8GB on the expansion to have 12GB of RAM?

And also, I have a spare [2GB Ram DDR3 Module @ 1333MHz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DUG7GTE). Can I use this? What will happen if I do?

EDIT: I took a screenshot of Task Manager if this has any significance. I don't think I can open the cover since the screw is covered by some plastic.
[image: TaskMan ScreenShot]

UPDATE: I bought a Kingston 8GB DDR3L Ram module, and the computer detects all of it to a maximum of 12GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 1 x DIMM socket for expansion up to 8 GB SDRAM

`up to`. That means that you can add another 4GiB SoDIMM (type DDR3L @800MHz) in order to get 8GiB useable memory. See @Jonno's post for more details.

You *might* be able to add more, but if a manufacturer claims up to X GiB than that either means:

1. That that really is the max (e.g. due to chipset limitations, max width of copper traces to the DIMM socket etc etc),
2. or that that only tested it with memory up to that much memory. E.g. because that was most which was available at the time the manual was written.

> And also I have a spare 2GB RAMDDR3 Module @ 1333MHz. 
>   Can I use this? What will happen if I do?

You *might* be able to use it. DDR3 memeory works by default at 1.5v. However DDR3L also needs to be able to work at 1.35 volt. (The L is for lower voltage).

What probabby will happen is that both old and new memory get 1.5volt. Both should be able to work with that.  Both will be clocked at 667MHz (which marketing writes as 1333MHz since it has two accesses per cycle).  And you will have 6Gib useable memory.

All this assumes that the CPU will also work with the higher voltage.
http://ark.intel.com/compare/84697,85212,85214 shows that at least three models of CPU's used for your model of laptop are not designed for anything but DDR3L though. Which might not mean anything. People reguarly feed more power to the memory and the on CPU die memory controller to archieve higher speeds and most of the time it tends to work. As for this specific model or these CPUs: I have no personal experience with these. I would add a secondf SoDIMM with the same specs as already on the laptop since that will guarantee 8GiB usueable and 8GiB is usually enough for a laptop. If you need more go to a shop and ask for a larger SoDIMM and for the shop to test if it works before they make the sale.

Recap: It probably will work.

Note that memory access will be slightly slower, but more memory usually trumps slower memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can have up to 8GB of RAM in your machine. The simplest way to find out how best to accomplish this would be to check the current RAM set up in your machine.

The [manual for your machine](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X455LA/0409_E10452_X455LA_LD_LN_V3_A.pdf) shows that the access panel for the RAM is very easy to get to

[image]

[image]

I would suggest opening this panel and checking whether it contains a stick already (With the machine turned off and the battery and power cable removed). If there is already a 4GB stick here, then you likely only have this one expansion slot (or the other is very buried somewhere) and would need to replace this stick with an 8GB DDR3 SODIMM. However, if the slot is empty, you would be able to add to your current system RAM with a 4GB DDR3 SODIMM, or add your 2GB module you currently have to bring you up to a total of 6GB.

As the page you've linked states there is 1x Socket for expansion, I assume it currently contains a 4GB stick, and you'd have to replace this, meaning your 2GB stick won't be useful in this scenario, but I don't know without looking in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop has 1 slot only. Either a 4 GB or 8 GB can be installed. Since you have 4 GB, you can remove it and install an 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

I've opened my ASUS X445LB's (sticker says K445L but dxdiag ang System Info says X455LB) RAM compartment. It has one slot but no RAM module installed. Saw some memory chips soldered into the board though. Can I install an 8GB RAM to that or can I only install another 4GB RAM because ASUS said "expansion up to 8 GB SDRAM" only?

Comment: The Board can only handle 8Gb by Manufacturers Guidelines so 4gb is what you can install and it still function properly you do more it may not boot.

Comment: Hello, OP here I finally got to buying a Module for my own computer just today and thought of updating my post here. I used an 8GB DDR3L from Kingston and so far it's working just fine.